# How is hashing safe if a given string always generates the same hash?

Tags: hash, cryptography

I am a newbie to hashing, and I understand that MD5 (I know it's broken) and SHA-1 are all fixed hashing algorithms, but given that most passwords are dictionary words or other similar passwords, what's the point of storing it in a hash if an attacker can use Google to backtrack the original password?

I mean, isn't SHA-1 or SHA-2 or any of those algorithms rendered useless?

Comment: This isn't really a specific programming question. Try searching [security.stackexchange.com](https://security.stackexchange.com), and if you can't find an answer, post a question there.

Comment: They're not with a non-dictionary password. Anyway, hashing isn't just used for passwords, that's one application.

Comment: I think this may be off-topic because this is about [security](http://security.stackexchange.com/) without directly involving programming.

Answer (score 2):

You're exactly right, simply hashing a raw password would be insecure. [Salting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_%28cryptography%29) is the solution to that. Instead of hashing just the password, hash the password + random_data and save random_data with the password.

Answer (score 1):

You need to salt your hashes to avoid being vulnerable to rainbow and 'google' attacks. Have a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_%28cryptography%29.